# Slicing keys of a dictionary to assign data

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

Right now I'm filling a dictionary via the following loop:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.choice(2, 10)
output = dict()
for i in range(10):
    output[i] = data[i]
```

Is there something more efficient in the spirit of `output[:] = data[:]`?

Solution: `output = dict(zip(range(10), np.random.choice(2, 10)))`

**Follow up:**
What if the key was a tuple?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.choice(2, 10)
output = dict()
for i in range(10):
    output[1, i] = data[i]
```

**Follow-follow up:**
I tried to reduce my actual question to a minimum, but ended up not asking what I ment to ask. What I'm actually doing is the following:

```
import numpy as np
output = dict()
for j in range(2):
    for k in range(3):
        data = np.random.choice(2, 10)
        for i in range(10):
            output[j, k, i] = data[i]
```

I tried to recycle the answers, but name errors popped up.

Comment: why don't you use `dict(enumerate(data.flatten(), 1))` or even `.flatten()` it then `zip` it with np.arange() and at the end pass the zip structure to `dict()` object.

Comment: see updated answer to address your follow-follow up question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** (after seeing the "follow-follow up"):

In the case you want tuples of higher dimensions, as per your "follow-follow up" question):

```py
def gen_nd(size):
    n = np.product(size)
    data = np.random.choice(2, n).tolist()
    idx = np.unravel_index(np.arange(n, dtype=int), size)
    return dict(zip(list(zip(*idx)), data))

>>> gen_nd((2,3,2))
{(0, 0, 0): 0,
 (0, 0, 1): 0,
 (0, 1, 0): 1,
 (0, 1, 1): 1,
 (0, 2, 0): 0,
 (0, 2, 1): 1,
 (1, 0, 0): 0,
 (1, 0, 1): 0,
 (1, 1, 0): 0,
 (1, 1, 1): 0,
 (1, 2, 0): 0,
 (1, 2, 1): 1}
```

and also:

```py
%timeit gen_nd((100, 100, 100))
647 ms ± 1.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For another 2x speedup:

```py
def gen_nd(size):
    m = len(size)
    n = np.product(size)
    data = np.random.choice(2, n).tolist()
    ranges = [np.arange(k) for k in size]
    idx = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*ranges, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, m).T.tolist()
    return dict(zip(list(zip(*idx)), data))

%timeit gen_nd((100, 100, 100))
297 ms ± 423 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Original answer**

How about simply (readable and fast):

```py
data = np.random.choice(2, 10)
output = dict(enumerate(data.tolist()))
```

For a `tuple` key (the "follow up question"):

```py
output = {(1, k): v for k, v in enumerate(data.tolist())}
```

**Speed**

If you are interested in speed, then here is a fun benchmark:

```py
def gen0(n):
    return dict(enumerate(data))

def tupgen0(n):
    data = np.random.choice(2, n)
    {(1,k): v for k, v in enumerate(data)}

def gen1(n):
    data = np.random.choice(2, n)
    return dict(enumerate(data.tolist()))

def tupgen1(n):
    data = np.random.choice(2, n)
    {(1,k): v for k, v in enumerate(data.tolist())}

def gen2(n):
    data = np.stack((np.arange(n, dtype=int), np.random.choice(2, n)))
    return dict(zip(*data.tolist()))

def tupgen2(n):
    data = np.stack((np.ones(n, dtype=int), np.arange(n, dtype=int), np.random.choice(2, n)))
    k, v = data[:2].tolist(), data[-1].tolist()
    return dict(zip(tuple(zip(*k)), v))

def gen3(n):
    return dict(zip(range(n), np.random.choice(2, n)))

def tupgen3(n):
    return dict(zip(((1, i) for i in range(n)), np.random.choice(2, n)))


n = 1_000_000

g0 = %timeit -o gen0(n)
g1 = %timeit -o gen1(n)
g2 = %timeit -o gen2(n)
g3 = %timeit -o gen3(n)

t0 = %timeit -o tupgen0(n)
t1 = %timeit -o tupgen1(n)
t2 = %timeit -o tupgen2(n)
t3 = %timeit -o tupgen3(n)
```

Gives:

```
202 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
114 ms ± 37.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
139 ms ± 53.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
203 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
350 ms ± 721 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
245 ms ± 321 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
305 ms ± 699 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
375 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So methods `gen1()` and `tupgen1()` are the fastest in their class.

Comment: Thanks, also very elegant.

Comment: Excellent. Yes speed matters.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) with a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) argument:

```
output = dict(zip(range(10), np.random.choice(2, 10)))
```

This makes every element from `range(10)` a key with elements from `np.random.choice(2, 10)` as  values.

If you want a key which is a tuple you can pass a generator to `zip` that will "pre-create" the tuples iterable:

```
output = dict(zip(((1, i) for i in range(10)), np.random.choice(2, 10)))
```

Another, less readable alternative is with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
output = dict(zip(map(lambda n: (1, n), range(10)), np.random.choice(2, 10)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a follow up question. What if the key was a tuple?

Comment: Ok. I feel it now. I actually came up with an alternative myself `dict(zip(zip([1 for i in range(10)], range(10)), np.random.choice(2, 10)))`

Comment: @clueless That is a bit less efficient since it actually creates a list and is using 2 `range` objects

Comment: It seems, however, that I cannot avoid the loop with the tuple.

Comment: @clueless not sure what you mean. My answer shows 2 examples without creating a list and using a single `range` object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229570/discussion-between-clueless-and-deepspace).